# Solve the equation $\frac{x^2-10x+15}{x^2-6x+15}=\frac{4x}{x^2-12x+15}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the equation $$\dfrac{x^2-10x+15}{x^2-6x+15}=\dfrac{4x}{x^2-12x+15}.$$
First we have $$x^2-6x+15\ne0$$ which is true for every $x$ ($D_1=k^2-ac=9-15<0$) and $$x^2-12x+15\ne0\Rightarrow x\ne6\pm\sqrt{21}.$$ Now $$(x^2-10x+15)(x^2-12x+15)=4x(x^2-6x+15)\\x^4-12x^3+15x^2-10x^3+120x-150x+15x^2-180x+225=\\=4x^3-24x^2+60x$$ which is an equation I can't solve. I tried to simplify the LHS by $$\dfrac{x^2-10x+15}{x^2-6x+15}=\dfrac{(x^2-6x+15)-4x}{x^2-6x+15}=1-\dfrac{4x}{x^2-6x+15}$$ but this isn't helpful at all. Any help would be appreciated! :) Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take out $x$ (clearly $x\ne 0$) we get: $$\dfrac{x(x-10+{15\over x})}{x(x-6+{15\over x})}=\dfrac{4x}{x(x-12+{15\over x})}.$$

Cancel $x$ and let $t=x+ {15\over x}$, then we have $${t-10\over t-6} = {4\over t-12}$$ or $$t^2-22t+120 = 4t-24$$
and so on...

Answer (score 2):

let $p=x^2+15,q=x$ then we have to solve $$\frac{p-10q}{p-6q}=\frac{4q}{p-12q}$$ $$\iff (p-10q)(p-12q)-4q(p-6q)=0$$ $$\iff (p - 8 q) (p - 18 q)=0$$ provided that $p\neq 6q,p\neq 12q$

Can you end it now?

Comment: Thank you for the response! May I ask you how did you get $$(p-8q)(p-18q)=0?$$ Did you expand the LHS?

Comment: @Medi divide the previous equation by $q^2$ and sub $t=\frac{p}{q}$ to get  a quadratic and factor!

Comment: After expanding it /the previous equation/, right?

Comment: @Medi yes ...,........

Comment: So now we will have $p=8q\Rightarrow x^2+15=8x$ or $p=18q\Rightarrow x^2+15=18x$?

Comment: @Medi again a quadratic go ahead!

Comment: Yes, I got it. But why can we divide by $q^2=x^2$? Should I check if $x=0$ is a solution?

Comment: @Medi I merely did that to get  a factorisation no need to check q=0

Answer (score 1):

[Componendo and dividendo](https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo/) yields:

$$\frac{x^2-6x+15}{x^2-10x+15} = \frac{x^2-12x+15}{4x}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{4x}{x^2 - 10x + 15} = \frac{x^2-16x+15}{4x} \tag{$\frac{a-b}{b} = \frac{c-d}{d}$}$$
$$\Rightarrow u=x^2-13x+15: \frac{4x}{u + 3x} = \frac{u - 3x}{4x}$$
$$\Rightarrow u^2 - 9x^2 = 16x^2$$
$$\Rightarrow (u - 5x)(u + 5x) = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow (x^2 - 18x + 15)(x^2 - 8x + 15) = 0$$